# React Select Unable to Remove Items From State Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React Select (https://react-select.com/home) which contains a bunch of options and the `onChange` handler will identify the selected items and push it into a State array.

The issue im running into is how to remove unselected items from the State array:

```
import Select from 'react-select'

const [selectedTeams, setSelectedTeams] = useState([]);

function manageSelectedTeams(event) {
    console.log('function triggered')
    setSelectedTeams([])

    event.forEach((team) => {
      console.log(team.value)
      setSelectedTeams(() => [...selectedTeams, team.value])
    })
}

data = [
    {
        label: "Example"
        value: "example"
    },
    {
        label: "Example"
        value: "example"
    },
    {
        label: "Example"
        value: "example"
    },
]

return (
<Select isMulti options={data} onChange={(e) => manageSelectedTeams(e)} closeMenuOnSelect={false} placeholder={"Teams will auto populate here once Location is defined above"} />
)
```

How would I tackle removing items from `selectedTeams` when a particular option is unselected/unticked

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-select handles the insert and delete for you so do not need to create a separate logic for it. When we use onChange the array of selected objects could be one possible parameter. You can refer to the same in the documentation. https://react-select.com/props

Thus you need to update your code as follows:

```
  function manageSelectedTeams(data) {
    let finalValueList = data.map((item) => item.value);
    console.log(finalValueList);
    setSelectedTeams(finalValueList);
  }
```

```
  return (
    <Select
      isMulti
      options={data}
      onChange={manageSelectedTeams} //UPDATED
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      placeholder={
        "Teams will auto populate here once Location is defined above"
      }
    />
  );
```